# How to refresh htop after sorting (via Shift+m)?

Tags: linux

I love using htop, but I have noticed that whenever I sort by a parameter (for example, Shift+m for sorting by Memory usage), the htop stats stop dynamically refreshing. Is this intended? I also notice this with top as well. Please advise.

Comment: `Ctrl-L` Refresh: redraw screen and recalculate values

Comment: Hm, Ctrl+l or Ctrl+L?  I've tried both, still seems to be sorted by memory usage.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Long day.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it only looks like it stops updating? I notice that when I switch to sort-by-memory, the list of processes is practically frozen relative to the default sort-by-cpu, but if I look carefully, the numbers are still changing regularly.